# Caching Google Maps for Offline Use (api v2)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'd like to implement this in an Android app, and be able to use app in offline mode. Is it possible to do this via the Android google maps api v2? App Google maps can do it, so I guess it is possible to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Google map android API V2 can save cached when you read. you can write a loop to read all map and get the cache & use as offline

Comment: I'd be grateful if you have same example or link. I'm now to Android.

Comment: @Fido: are you sure that it is possible to directly get the cache map ? I know that the cache is done...but I can not find a way to manage it.

Comment: @AntoineP the cache save what we read, so my idea is write a loop and read all region we want for each level. It just an idea, i haven't try it yet

Comment: The device/OS reserves the right to clear your cache at any time so this method is not reliable.